# Replacing GROUP BY by SELECT DISTINCT when not using aggregation function in SELECT

Tags: sql, group-by, query-optimization, having, unnest

As a part of a past university assignment I was given this nested SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.playerId
FROM Player P
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(G.id)
    FROM Game G
    WHERE G.playerId = P.playerId
) >10
```

The task was to unnest the query. As preparation for the exams I now tried to solve this task again and came up with a solution similar to this (not 100% sure about the right syntax but I guess the intention is clear):

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.playerId
FROM Player P, Game G
WHERE G.playerId = P.playerId
HAVING COUNT(G.id) >10
```

However, the official solution suggested this query:

```
SELECT P.playerId
FROM Player P, Game G
WHERE P.playerId = G.playerId
GROUP BY P.playerId
HAVING COUNT(G.id) > 10
```

So, my question is, whether this would just be an alternative solution or whether it is just not possible to have a `SELECT DISTINCT` without `GROUP BY` when using `HAVING + aggregate function`? Essentially, the result of `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` should be the same but I'm just not sure about leaving out `GROUP BY` when using a `HAVING` clause.

Thanks in advance for any insights on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is:

```
SELECT G.playerId
FROM Game G
GROUP BY G.playerId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10;
```

The `JOIN` is totally unnecessary.  And if you do want to join, use `JOIN`, not a comma.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. However, I guess that, despite a join being unnecessary in this case, the goal of the task was for us to unnest the query by using a join as it was explicitly asked to say why the specific type of join is important to unnest the query.

Comment: Most databases will not accept `HAVING` without a corresponding `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Samaranth . . . Very curious question for a query that only needs one table.